# How to delete Kafka "ghost" consumers?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

When I use Kafka Tool: `https://www.kafkatool.com/` I see additional consumer groups that I do not see with `kafka-consumer-groups.sh`

I'm assuming that the additional consumer groups are coming from Zookeeper while `kafka-consumer-groups.sh` only shows what it sees on the brokers.

Is there a way to delete these "ghost" groups? They are not used? Can I manually browse zookeeper and go delete those nodes?

Answer (score 0):

IIRC, KafkaTool uses Zookeeper, not `--bootstrap-server` AdminClient protocol to list groups that `kafka-consumer-groups` does...

Also, `kafka-console-consumer` creates random groups that get hidden in the `kafka-consumer-groups` output.

While you could remove them from Zookeeper, all inactive consumer groups will automatically go away, as per the offsets retention policies over time, and having them there doesn't cause any performance penalties.

Comment: Thanks but it's annoying to see all those random consumers. So i want to clean them up. And Kafka Tool seems to support both, but you can't pick Zoo or Bootstrap. It seems that zoo is mandatory regardless if you specify bootstrap servers.

Comment: There is code in this post to remove groups created by the new consumer api - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37741936/how-to-delete-kafka-consumer-group-created-via-new-consumer-api?rq=1

Comment: It's a zookeeper thing. The new API doesn't even see those consumers. That's why I call them "ghosts"

Comment: Well, unless you're running clients that are over 5 years old, then you shouldn't be using `zookeeper.connect` as a consumer property

Comment: If you exec into a broker you can execute the following bash script directly:

/opt/kafka/bin/kafka-consumer-groups.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --list | while read GROUP; do \
  STATUS=$(/opt/kafka/bin/kafka-consumer-groups.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --describe --group "$GROUP" | awk '{print $6}'); \
  if [ "$STATUS" = "Empty" ]; then \
    echo "Deleting consumer group: $GROUP"; \
    /opt/kafka/bin/kafka-consumer-groups.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --delete --group "$GROUP"; \
  else \
    echo "Skipping active consumer group: $GROUP"; \
  fi; \
done

Comment: You shouldn't need to exec into any broker to run that